TestFlight - Could not install app. The profile can't be installed
I have just uploaded a new build to TestFlight. When I tried to download the new version, I got this message:
Could not install .
The profile can't be installed. Please try again.
I cannot install the previous builds either. In XCode I have selected the 'Automatically manage signing' checkbox.
Any ideas what it could be the problem?

We are experiencing this issue as well.

We are experiencing the issue too.

Seems like it is likely an issue on Apple's side, lots of people having issues
https://x.com/nethead/status/1799236372680609931

Thanks for your reply! Yes, it looks like it's an Apple issue.

You can check the status directly form apple
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/
