Unable to install build from TestFlight. ”The profile can’t be installed”
Getting error ‘Couldn’t install app. The profile can’t be installed. Try again.’
On new builds in TestFlight. The previous versions worked fine. After the new build upload to TestFlight, neither new nor old versions are getting installed for new users.

I am having this same issue. It wasn't happening earlier today, I tried generating new distribution and provisioning certificates and that did not work either.

I'm having this issue too. Seeing as this was originally asked 10 minutes ago, and 3 people are seeing it, there might be a recent issue with TestFlight lol

I'm having the same issue

I can't even find any previous times people have seen this same error, there are similar ones, but none that I can find with the exact same text, except for one Twitter user, but I can't view that tweet without an account.

Same issue here, I tried so many different signing profiles or certificates.
Seems to be an issue with Apple's Testflight

I am having the same issue after deploying a new build as well. I found another SO thread here which links to a X.com thread where this happened on June 7th and apparently resolved itself after a few hours. For me, this has been going on for about 2 hours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78644430/testflight-could-not-install-app-the-profile-cant-be-installed

Looks like Apple is now aware of this issue...
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

App Store Connect - TestFlight - Performance
Performance Today, 8:19 PM - ongoing
Some users are affected
Users are experiencing a problem with this service. We are working to
resolve this issue.


Flagging a similar thread in Developer Forums. Seems to be an issue on Apples end.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/757564
